# simple notepad data input program needs fixing

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, python-3.4

Hi I recently had this program running fine but after fiddling round with it now it doesn't work because when i run it in the shell when the program asks "do you want to enter a user" and I type "yes" it doesn't ask for the user to input he/shes name, DOB in form 00/00/0000, run time, postcode. It just prints "do you want to see your records?" If anyone could help quick it would be much appreciated p.s im really new so I dont 100% understand some things at the moment.

```
def openfile1(name,dob,time,postcode):
file=open('runnerdata.txt', 'a')
file.write(name+":")
file.write(dob+":")
file.write(time+":")
file.write(postcode+ ":\n")
file.close()

while True: 
    enter=input("Do you want to enter a user? ")
    if enter=="no":
        file=open('runnerdata.txt', 'r')
        list=(file.readlines())
        enter2=input("Do you want to see your records? ")
        if enter2=="no":
                break
        elif enter2=="yes":
        name2=input("Enter name to see your records ")
        for line in list:
            if line.split(":")[0]==name2:
                print(line)

    elif enter=="yes":
        name=input("Enter name ")
        dob=input("Enter your DOB in form 00/00/0000 ")
        time=input("Enter your run time ")
        postcode=input("Enter your postcode ")
        openfile1(name,dob,time,postcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def openfile1(name,dob,time,postcode):
    file=open('runnerdata.txt', 'a')
    file.write(name+":")
    file.write(dob+":")
    file.write(time+":")
    file.write(postcode+ ":\n")
    file.close()

while True:
    enter=input("Do you want to enter a user? ")
    if enter=="no":
        file=open('runnerdata.txt', 'r')
        list=(file.readlines())
        enter2=input("Do you want to see your records? ")
        if enter2=="no":
                break
        elif enter2=="yes":
            name2=input("Enter name to see your records ")
        for line in list:
            if line.split(":")[0]==name2:
                print(line)

    elif enter=="yes":
        name=input("Enter name ")
        dob=input("Enter your DOB in form 00/00/0000 ")
        time=input("Enter your run time ")
        postcode=input("Enter your postcode ")
        openfile1(name,dob,time,postcode)
```

Try this